# Matlab: read all wave in a folder

Tags: matlab, directory, wave

I want to read all wave files in a folder in Matlab. I use this code to open theses files:

```
Files=dir('path folder.wav');

for k=1:length(Files)
      FileNames=Files(k).name;
  [s,fs]=wavread(FileNames);
end
```

but this code doesn't work, wave files do not open. Why? Can you help me?

Comment: Is it possible that `dir` isn't returning any files?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?  `wavread` was removed after R2015b

Comment: My version is MATLAB R2013a

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it does not read wave files

Comment: @user3582433 So there is no error? `s` and `fs` are empty? what does `Files(1).name` return?

Comment: yes, s and Fs are empty

Comment: What does `Files(1).name` return? Are you sure that your files are not corrupted?

Comment: Are you just getting the contents of the last file by any chance?

Comment: i'm going to guess that you don't have a file named `path folder.wav`. You need to use a wildcard in your `dir` command. `dir('path folder/*.wav')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dir() command returns only file names - not the full path.
So, possible you just need to restore full path:

```
dirMask = 'path folder.wav';
wavRoot = fileparts(dirMask);

Files=dir(dirMask);

for k=1:length(Files)
    FileNames = fullfile(wavRoot, Files(k).name);
    [s,fs] = wavread(FileNames);
end
```